# create multiple dataframes from unique values of a cloumn

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with columns(issue_id,summary, source_id). The source_id has values ranging from 1 to 3.
I want to create multiple dataframes having name df_1, df_2,df_3  as per the values in source_id.

I tried groupby and it gave a dict. but converting dict to dataframe is giving only 1 dataframe.

data_dict={'df'+str(i): grp for i , grp in df.groupby('Source_sys')}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict,orient = 'index')

output:
0
df1     Issue ...
df2     Issue ...
df3     Issue ...

Comment: @jezrael could you help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to filter the dataframe on `source_id`. For example the below would generate a dataframe where source_id is equal to 1:

```py
df[df['source_id']==1]
```

If you want to assign this to a new variable you can do:

```py
df_1 = df[df['source_id']==1].copy()
```

Note the addition of `.copy()` since you are creating slice of the original dataframe. If you wish to change df_1 in anyway in any further code, having `.copy()` here will avoid throwing the [SettingWithCopyWarning](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/).

#### Edit - accounting for if new values of 'source_id' are added

You could build a dictionary comprehension of dataframes and use the unique values of `'source_id'` to do so:

```py
dfs = {f'df_{n}': df[df['source_id'] == n] for n in df['source_id'].unique()}
```

Note the use of an f string here which is only available in 3.6 or higher. If you're on an older version you can replace `f'df_{n}'` with `'df_{}'.format(n)`.

Now if you want to access any of these dataframes alone you can use the keys of the dictionary:

```py
dfs['df_1']
```

Comment: direct value assignement might not help the solution. if there is another source_id is added, i dont want to change the code.

Comment: I've edited my solution so that you can create a dictionary with the number of dataframes as unique values of source_id. Does this help?

Comment: Thank you, this is working. I have another problem. I dont want to manually pass parameter 'df_1' for get the dataframe. I tried loop, but not sure how to copy the dataframe to a separate variable at each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is delete other columns and assign different name. @krishna